# Java beginner question - String.format

Tags: java, formatting

When I call the displayTime12hrclock method in another class, it refuses to print out AM or PM. I can't work out why.

```
public class Tuna {


    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;



    public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){
        hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;

        hour = ((h>= 0 && h <=24 ? h:0));
        minute = ((m>= 0 && m <=60 ? m:0));
        second = ((s>= 0 && s <=60 ? s:0));

    }

    public String displayTime(){
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour,minute,second);

    }

    public String displayTime12hrclock(){
    return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", ((hour==0 || hour ==12)?12:hour%12), minute, second, (hour >=12)? "AM":"PM");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you pass 4 parameters and evaluate only 3 in your format.

```
"%d:%02d:%02d" <- here are only 3 parameters referenced
```

Answer (score 4):

You pass *four* parameters to `format` but display only three. Try this:

```
return String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour==0 || hour ==12)?12:hour%12), minute, second, (hour >=12)? "AM":"PM");
```

Comment: @Ravin - if we have *too few* arguments, then we get a `MissingFormatArgumentException` at run time. With too many arguments we have to find the bug manually (didn't know that actually, so thanks for the question :D )

Answer (score 1):

Your String.format is missing a %s.  The following should work...

```
String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour==0 || hour ==12)?12:hour%12), minute, second, (hour >=12)? "AM":"PM");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the format there are only 3 fields %d, you pass 4 to it (hour, minute, second, AM/PM).

The last one is ignored

As a side note, when you get more confortable, check

java.util.Date
java.util.Calendar
java.util.SimpleDateFormat

Java API is extensive and may take a time to learn, but does a lot of things!

Answer (score 0):

You only have three values in your format.

Try changing it into this:

```
String.format("%d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour==0 || hour ==12)?12:hour%12), minute, second, (hour >=12)? "AM":"PM");
```

Note the last `%s`.  You only had three references (`%d`) in your format, so it was only taking the first three arguments specified.  By adding `%s` you include the forth argument as a string.